# Cannot ping AWS instance (Yes, I added a security group)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have set up the AWS EC2 instance and it is running. When I try to ping from my local box it is not available. None of the solutions I have found seem to work. I've added a rule to the security group:

```
Custom ICMP Rule - IPv4, Echo Reply, N/A, 0.0.0.0/0
```

And I've completely disabled the Windows Firewall (just for testing). I still cannot ping this instance.

Answer (score 5):

You need to allow `Echo Request` not `Echo Reply`.

[image]